# Keycloak admin client Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, keycloak

I use the Keycloak admin client in Spring boot for user management (add, update, delete).
and I expose CRUD operations as apis.
The problem I have is that when I implemented the unit tests, the users I created are added to Keycloak, I want to know if there is an option to mock this, I don't want to pollute the Keycloak users with the users used in the tests.

*Note*: I use Keycloak 17 and Spring Boot 2.5.6.

Comment: Depending upon your tests, you could create a temporary realm with the same options as the realm you want to test, create the user there and then simply delete the realm in the end.

Comment: thank you for this proposition,i would like to see if there is an option to mock this process of creation without interacting with the real keycloak itself.
or if there is an option to rollback these operations after tests are done.